# Trouble in ajax php to find palce use pincode

Tags: php, ajax

I am developing a small applicatopn using php with ajax to get place when user enter a pincode. Now I'm shore to my aim, but now I am getting some unwanted results but incluing the actual result.

This is my code...my html code is given below

```
<label for="pincode">Pin-Code:</label>
     <input name="pincode" type="text" class="text" id="pincode"  /><div id="section1"></div>
```

and my javascript code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
         $('#pincode').keyup(function() {
                //ajax request
                $.ajax({
                     url: "pincode_check.php",
                    data: {
                        'pincode' : $('#pincode').val()
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) { <!--console.log(data.success);-->
                        if(data.success){
                            $.each(data.results[0].address_components, function(index, val){
                                 console.log(index+"::"+val.long_name); 
                                 /*alert(index+"::"+val.long_name); */                       
                                 $('#section1').append( val.long_name);
                             });    
                        }       
                    },      
                });
            });
       });


    </script>
```

in pincode_check.php

```
<?php 
    $pincode=$_REQUEST['pincode'];
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$pincode.'&sensor=false');
    $response= json_decode($geocode); //Store values in variable
    $lat = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; //Returns Latitude
    $long = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng; // Returns Longitude
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$long.'&sensor=false');
    $data= json_decode($geocode);

    if($data==true)
    { // Check if address is available or not
        $data->results[0]->formatted_address ;   
        $data->success=true;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else {
        $data->success= false;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

When i enter a pincode , for eg: 690561
The output is

*Les JumeauxCourzieuRhôneRhone-AlpesFrance6967015Heilige HuisjesZevenaarZevenaarGelderlandThe Netherlands6905 **AAAnayadi Edakkad** RdThottuvaPallickalKollamKeralaIndia690561Yitzhak Rabin HighwayIsraelYitzhak Rabin HighwayIsrael328BoulevardAndersonAnderson CountySouth CarolinaUnited States29621164Lenina avenueOrdzhonikidzevs'kyi districtZaporizhiaZaporiz'ka city councilZaporiz'ka oblastUkraine*

But I need only **AAAnayadi Edakkad** . Please help me to filter out this output.

Comment: can you post your response?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm finding it really hard to understand what you are doing and what is going wrong.

Comment: i just update my code about php ajax .plese look my question above

Comment: post your $data json here to see

Comment: Can you mention pincode and its actual result?

Comment: yes, ofcourse , i have updated my code . pls take a look at this.

Comment: ok..sir pincode is  690561 result is Anayadi Edakkad Rd

Comment: i need place name when we enter 691523 this then we get RdMain Central Road not mention place ..plese help to get place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly check this your pin code and press enter key

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#pincode').keyup(function (e) {
                 if (e.keyCode == 13) {


                    //ajax request
                    $.ajax({
                         url: "pin_request.php",
                        data: {
                            'pincode' : $('#pincode').val()
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) { <!--console.log(data.success);-->
                            if(data.success){
                                //console.log(data.results[0].formatted_address.split(','))
                                var long_address=data.results[0].formatted_address.split(',');
                                console.log(long_address[0]);
                                $('#section1').append(long_address[0]);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                 }
                });

           });


        </script>
```

Comment: iam update this code with my program but result not got

Comment: result not got variable value not post by ajax

Comment: check this in function what value is getting $('#pincode').val()

Comment: in javascript function pincode value not post to pincode_check.php

Comment: sorry replace  url: "pin_request.php", with  url: "pincode_check.php",
i have change to my file .. change it with ur file name

Comment: no got value when it  place $('#pincode').val() inside the if (e.keyCode == 13) conditional statement

Comment: yes i changed ur code and repalce currect file name .but not working

Comment: okay alert($('#pincode').val() ); before if() and check is alert provide value of text box.. when u insert any value in text then press enter key ..

Comment: when we enter first digit it alert...next digits not dispalay

Comment: but same code is working fine on my system, check in console ur ajax request is sending any value?